# How to set provisioning profile when making new target

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have created my first ever iOS app. I am basically an android developer. and I know how to do things in android like the one I am trying to do in iOS

Right now I have made one app and I want to change a little and deliver it to my another client. For this I have to change only 4 things

- URL
- APP NAME
- BUNDLE ID
- SOME PASSWORD STRINGS

now as I have created a new target by following [this](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/) tutorial, I have seen the red mark on provisioning profile. **It says "NAME_MY_PROVISIONING PROFILE" has app ID com.mypreviousclient.bundle.identifier which does not match the bundle id of my new client**

It clearly tells that the bundle id I just created is not inside my provisioning profile.

But I really do not know what to do now? What should I do now?

Comment: create new provisioning profile for new app in apple developer console.

Comment: for this you need to login your apple developer portal and itune. if its a different application.

Comment: @MRizwan33 I logged in to my account. There are certificates , APp IDs and Devices and last one is Provisioning Profile. 
now I only need to create Provisioning profile? or app Id Also ?

Comment: yes you need to create new bundle id with name same as you kept in xcode.

Comment: then you have to create new app in itune with that bundle id.

Comment: let me try ......

Comment: yes try it and let me know where you stuck again.

Comment: app Id gets created, now whats next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184877/discussion-between-mrizwan33-and-shararti-kaki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing bundle id in xcode for new app. You have to also create that bundle id in apple developer console. Here are the steps.

1. create bundle id in apple developer console.
2. Now you can create application in itune.
3. create certificates.
4. create provisioning profiles.
5. set them into xcode and run.

Happy coding.